# Specify script to run with install command automake

Tags: bash, make, automake, autotools

I'm currently building a large package which is handled with automake.
Package is composed by C,C++ and Python.
So far i have good results with C/C++ but i'm blocked when it comes to python dependencies.

I personnaly run a script when i'm installing, and i'd like to run it whenever `make install` is called.
For now it's called by configure.ac but it's run at unecessary times.

The script is doing 3 things :

- Placing some python files in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/(dist|site)-packages
- Installing a homemade python module
- Checking for python & program dependencies such as geckodriver
  and install those if necessary

I know that makefiles generated by automake are "creating commands"  that are triggered when `install` or `uninstall` by example, and i'd like to know how to tell makefile.am to call somescript.sh when install is called and to call someOtherscript.sh when uninstall is called to remove what my program installed.

A bit like preinst script in debian packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually found a way to handle python with autotools. Makefile.am allow you to override install and uninstall like this :

```
install-exec-local:
    cd src/ && python setup.py install --record $(pythondir)/installed_files.txt

uninstall-local:
    cat $(pythondir)/installed_files.txt | xargs rm -rf \
    rm -r $(sysconfdir)/nina
```

special thanks to Kevin Brown for his amazing tutorial.

https://blog.kevin-brown.com/programming/2014/09/24/combining-autotools-and-setuptools.html